# How to create RRG (Relative Rotation Graph) using chartJs or D3 with tooltip?

Tags: d3.js, chart.js

I want create RRG using any open source using ChartJS or D3Js

I have tried this, but am unable to draw quadrants forked example https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-forked-m1zug2

Expectation should be like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpRDW.png)

Comment: any suggestions for this

Comment: @kikon - could you please guide this case

Answer (score 0):

You can create something similar using chart.js; almost anything can be charted with it, as it is an open system with strong support for customization. Still, how much effort it would take to implement a type of chart that is not natively supported may vary.

For the type of chart you describe in your image, I'd go with the following:

- a mixed chart: [lines](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) with [stacking](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#stacked-area-chart) and fill to draw quadrants
- a [bubble plot](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html) for ... the bubbles
- [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/types/label.html) for the texts in the corners
- [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/options.html) for the labels of the bubbles

Here's an example that can get you started, containing all those ingredients as a proof of concept - there's still a lot to do to achieve something useful in production. In particular, the tooltip is just the standard version, so you'll need to configure it using the extensive set of options available in the library (see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip)).

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)
const xMin = 90, xMax = 110;
const yMin = 90, yMax = 110;

const xHalf = (xMin+xMax)/2, xHalfPlus = xHalf + 1e-6,
    yHalf = (yMin + yMax)/2, yHalfDist = (yMax - yMin)/2;
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                {x: xMin, y: yHalf},
                {x: xHalf, y:yHalf},
                {x: xHalfPlus, y: null},
                {x: xMax, y: null}
            ],
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 160, 0, 0.5)",
            pointRadius: 0,
            showLine: false,
            stacked: true,
            order: 1
        }, {
            data: [
                {x: xMin, y: yHalfDist},
                {x: xHalf, y:yHalfDist},
                {x: xHalfPlus, y: null},
                {x: xMax, y: null}
            ],
            fill: "-1",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5)",
            pointRadius: 0,
            showLine: false,
            stacked: true,
            order: 2
        },
            {
            data: [
                {x: xMin, y: null},
                {x: xHalf, y: null},
                {x: xHalfPlus, y: yHalf},
                {x: xMax, y:yHalf}
            ],
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)",
            pointRadius: 0,
            showLine: false,
            order: 1
        },
        {
            data: [
                {x: xMin, y: null},
                {x: xHalf, y: null},
                {x: xHalfPlus, y: yHalfDist},
                {x: xMax, y:yHalfDist}
            ],
            fill: "-1",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 192, 160, 0.5)",
            pointRadius: 0,
            showLine: false,
            order: 2
        },
        {
            type: "bubble",
            data: [
                {x: 101, y: 97.2, r: 18, label: "ABCD"},
                {x: 102, y: 103.4, r: 11, label: "WEDW"},
                {x: 103, y: 102.2, r: 11, label: "CESA"},
                {x: 98, y: 101.4, r: 11, label: "QWEX"}
            ],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(64, 64, 128, 0.7)',
            order: 0,
            label: "my data"
        }
    ]},
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: "linear",
                min: xMin,
                max: xMax,
            },
            y: {
                min: yMin,
                max: yMax,
                stacked: true,
            }
        },
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                labels:{
                    filter(ctx){
                        // no legend for the four quadrants
                        if(ctx.datasetIndex < 4) return false;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            },
            datalabels:{
                anchor:'center',
                align: 'center',
                color: '#000',
                clamp: true,
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: function(value) {
                    //console.log(value)
                    return value.label || ''
                },
            },
            annotation: {
                annotations: {
                    label1: {
                        type: 'label',
                        content: 'Lagging',
                        xValue: xMin,
                        yValue: yMin,
                        position:{x: "start", y: "end"},
                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
                    },
                    label2: {
                        type: 'label',
                        content: 'Weakening',
                        xValue: xMax,
                        yValue: yMin,
                        position:{x: "end", y: "end"},
                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
                    },
                    label3: {
                        type: 'label',
                        content: 'Improving',
                        xValue: xMin,
                        yValue: yMax,
                        position:{x: "start", y: "start"},
                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
                    },
                    label4: {
                        type: 'label',
                        content: 'Leading',
                        xValue: xMax,
                        yValue: yMax,
                        position:{x: "end", y: "start"},
                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
                    }
                },
                font: {
                    size: 22
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="width:900px; height: 700px">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/2.2.1/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js" integrity="sha512-qF3T5CaMgSRNrxzu69V3ZrYGnrbRMIqrkE+OrE01DDsYDNo8R1VrtYL8pk+fqhKxUBXQ2z+yV/irk+AbbHtBAg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Have a look to the chartjs-plugin-annotation sample about magic quadrant: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/2.2.1/samples/box/gradient.html

Comment: @user2057925 That's cool, I  thought there's a possibility that someone did that already, also in d3. You should write an answer using that.

Comment: I don't know d3, sorry.... I'm a fun (and user, contributor) of chart.js

Comment: the OP mentioned d3 in the title and (since its chart part is more of a set of recipes of how to draw your own chart), there are thousands of chart types out there so I thought it more likely someone did this type already in d3; but it's good it's also in chartjs annotations.