# Different Line Chart border colors for positive and negative values using Chart Js

Tags: chart.js

I have created a line chart using charts JS, but I am unable to apply the line color change. Expectation should be: if the y value is less than 0 (zero) the line should be red and if it's greater than 0(zero) green.

I have forked my code here: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-forked-yy6jzr?file=/src/AreaChart.jsx).

I have tried to use dataset segment borderColor; if y value <0 I set the color red, else if y value >0 the color is green, but it does not work as expected.

In the dataset I have `{x: 42380, y: negative value (which is near by zero)}` followed by `{x: 42500, y: POSITIVE value(which very first positive value)}]`; the segment between these two points is showing red
despite the fact that the negative part from y = -185 to zero, is much shorter than the positive part, from zero to  y = 2000

Comment: line is less than zero??? What does it mean?? Are you talking about length? if so, then which length?

Comment: @Developer - See the example here [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-forked-yy6jzr?file=/src/AreaChart.jsx%5C]. Line Border color wants to show green when it above the zero (y-axis) and when its below the zero (y-axis ) red.

Comment: quick fix: use `(ctx.p1.parsed.y + ctx.p0.parsed.y)/2 >= 0` in `getBorderColor`; still, a better solution would be to interpolate the segment that intersects `y=0`

Comment: @kikon - Thanks!!!! It looks fine with `(ctx.p1.parsed.y + ctx.p0.parsed.y)/2 >= 0`. Is it possible to give background as gradient right now I have used solid colors for that. current code is here [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-forked-yy6jzr?file=/src/AreaChart.jsx:327-335].

Comment: @kikon - Could you please suggest for this as well [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76214710/how-to-create-rrg-relative-rotation-graph-using-chartjs-or-d3-with-tooltip
]

Comment: @FrontEnd Actually the gradient idea is the way to go for a good solution to your actual problem with the color of the line. I'll write up a solution based on that in a few hours, if nobody else does sooner.  As for background, you could certainly use gradients; see [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html) and [this one](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/radial-gradient.html) for inspiration. If you have specific issues there, you should ask another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for changing the color of the line depending on the sign of the points was already implemented by setting the `borderColor` for [`segment`s](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/segments.html) and it worked fine for all segments that had both ends of the same sign; the config object was

```js
datasets:[{
    data: ....
    .......
    segment: {
        borderColor: (ctx) => {
            return getBorderColor(ctx);
        }
    },
}]
```

with the actual computation implemented in the function `getBorderColor` (slightly modified from the original to simplify the introduction of my extension below):

```js
const getBorderColor = 
        (ctx, colPositive = "green", colNegative = "red") => {
    return ctx.p0.parsed.y >= 0 ? colPositive : colNegative;
};
```

To adapt this to work for segments that intersect the x axis, the solution I found was to set the color as a [`LinearGradient`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html) with four [color stops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasGradient/addColorStop) described by this table:

```
      point:    p0       x-axis intersection      p1
coordinates:  (x0, y0)        (_, 0)           (x1, y1)
   fraction:     0             frac               1
      color:   green ------> green|red --------> red
```

where `frac` is easy to compute from the coordinates of the two points. One can see this is not actually a visual gradient, the change of color from "green" to "red" (used as an example) is done at the same point, the intersection of the segment to the x axis.

Here's the code with explanations in comments:

```js
const getBorderColor = (ctx, colPositive = "green", colNegative = "red") => {
    if (ctx.p0.parsed.y * ctx.p1.parsed.y < 0) {
        // if the segment changes sign from p0 to p1
        const x0 = ctx.p0.parsed.x,
            x1 = ctx.p1.parsed.x,
            y0 = ctx.p0.parsed.y,
            y1 = ctx.p1.parsed.y,
            dataset = ctx.chart.data.datasets[ctx.datasetIndex],
            //identify the correct axes used for the dataset
            xAxisId = dataset.xAxisId ?? "x",
            yAxisId = dataset.yAxisId ?? "y",
            //transform values to pixels
            x0px = ctx.chart.scales[xAxisId].getPixelForValue(x0),
            x1px = ctx.chart.scales[xAxisId].getPixelForValue(x1),
            y0px = ctx.chart.scales[yAxisId].getPixelForValue(y0),
            y1px = ctx.chart.scales[yAxisId].getPixelForValue(y1);
        
        // create gradient form p0 to p1
        const gradient = ctx.chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(x0px, y0px, x1px, y1px);
        // calculate frac - the relative length of the portion of the segment
        // from p0 to the point where the segment intersects the x axis
        const frac = Math.abs(y0) / (Math.abs(y0) + Math.abs(y1));
        // set colors at the ends of the segment
        const [col_p0, col_p1] =
            y0 > 0 ? [colPositive, colNegative] : [colNegative, colPositive];
        gradient.addColorStop(0, col_p0);
        gradient.addColorStop(frac, col_p0);
        gradient.addColorStop(frac, col_p1);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, col_p1);
        return gradient;
    }
    return ctx.p0.parsed.y >= 0 ? colPositive : colNegative;
};
```

and [the fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-forked-cjj7px?file=/src/AreaChart.jsx:409-1887) of the original codesandbox.